# std::ifstream doesn't open file

Tags: c++, io, fstream, ifstream

Im trying to open a file, like everyone else but it doesn't work.
I wasted too much time looking for solutions and stuff but nothing!
In my other project, it works, but not here.

I don't know if this is related to anything but i still have a std::ofstream ("stream" variable) open while opening the std::ifstream

btw. the file path is:
C:\Users\no\Desktop\GlassStudios\GlassEngine\Source\x64\Debug\Content\Asset.txt

and changing the backslashes to slashes ("/") doesn't work either

Here's my code:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < tmpfl.size(); i++) // tmpfl is a std::list<std::string>
        {
            std::ifstream data(tmpfl.begin()->c_str(), std::ios::binary); // Stream is empty all the time
            tmpfl.pop_front();

            int start = stream.tellp(); // this is for an unrelated part

            while (!stream.eof()) // this is for an unrelated part
            {
                WriteEncrypted(key, (char)data.get(), &stream); // this is for an unrelated part
            }

            data.close(); // this is for an unrelated part

            int end = stream.tellp(); // this is for an unrelated part
        }
```

pls help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "\\" in your file path rather than \?

(Like this)

C:\\Users\\no\\Desktop\\GlassStudios\\GlassEngine\\Source\\x64\\Debug\\Content\\Asset.txt

Also, sometimes antiviruses block your programs from opening files in other locations, you may have to manually go into your antivirus and allow your programs to access other locations on your computer.

Comment: No, the \\ is escaped, so it would technically be only \
and disabling the anti virus doesn't work either